# How to focus on the textbox again after enter key is pressed?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

This might be a trivial question but I have a simple textbox and a button that will add the item entered in the textbox into a list, as follows:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Add New Tag" data-bind="value: tagToAdd, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', executeOnEnter: addTag" />
<button data-bind="click: addTag">+ ADD</button>
```

The program works as intended, but every time after I hit enter and the item is added into the list, the "+ ADD" button is focused and I am unable to type in the textbox unless I use my mouse to click on the textbox again. Is there a way to focus the textbox so I can simply enter my data, press enter, then directly enter a new value without having to pick up the mouse?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the setFocus attribute on an observable and after adding set the attribute to true;

```
var focusOnMe = ko.observable(false);

var addSomething= function () {
     // Do something
     focusOnMe(true);
};        

<input data-bind="value: someText, hasFocus: focusOnMe "/>
```